# Webdriver unable to hit submit button due no such element found error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Webdriver unable to hit submit button due no such element found error. Below is the code and error shown in the console while running the script.

```
public void passwordmatch() {
    driver.findElement(By.id("encrypted_pwd")).sendKeys(pwd);
    driver.findElement(By.id("confirm_pwd")).sendKeys(confirm_pwd);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='submit-btn']//*[@type='image']")).click();
    if(pwd ==confirm_pwd) {
        System.out.println("Password Match");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Password doesn't Match");
    }
}
```

Error message is :

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
    {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='submit-btn']//*[@type='image']"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.04 seconds
```

Comment: Please can you share the HTML for the page?

Comment: Website url is : http://talentrack.in/register, you can check here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following HMTL for the submit button:

`<input src="/images/application/modules/default/submit-btn.jpg" class="submit-btn" type="image">`

The reason you are receiving a NoSuchElementException when using `//*[@id='submit-btn']//*[@type='image']` as a locator is firstly because the first part of the XPath - `//*[@id='submit-btn']` is looking for any element in the page whose *id* attribute is equal to `submit-btn`, whereas the required element has a *class* attribute equal to `submit-btn`.

The second part of the XPath - `//*[@type='image']` is looking for a child element with a *type* attribute equal to 'image' however the required element does not have any children.

Try using the following code in the offending line and let me know if it works:

`driver.findElement(By.className("submit-btn")).click();`

---

On an unrelated note, the line where you are trying to compare the passwords - `if(pwd ==confirm_pwd) {` is likely to be incorrect as you are comparing whether the two strings are pointing to the same String object.

You should instead use the `.equals()` method in a manner similar to:

`if (pdw.equals(confirm_pwd)) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing everything after the first ]. Then give it a go.

As in:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='submit-btn']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Hi try doing the following.

`driver.findElement(By.id("confirm_pwd")).submit();`

above code will submit the form in which element with id 'confirm_pwd' is present.
i am sure this will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi nitin, I have already used this but it is not working. thnx

Comment: can you check with this xpath //form[@id='form_register']/div[1]/input
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form_register']/div[1]/input")).click();